# What is the best approach to align equations in order to organize common terms in a equation? (aligned vs array)

Tags: align, arrays, best-practices

This question is about opinions and experiences of users.

What is the best approach to align equations in order to organize common terms in a equation?

What is preferable in the particular case described below? (aligned vs array)

I have been using LaTeX for a while and always bothers me each time I use a certain command, someone says "hey, you should have used this other command". Although I like to have options, sometimes it is just not simple to find out the best option among them. In this particular case, we are talking about the package [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Both environment are inside equation in order to have only one equation number. The idea is to use the right alignment of each column, such as all constants are aligned and numbers are placed left. It produces a very neat style.

Discussion about the MWE below:

1. I had to use more `&`s in `aligned` in order to align the constants while `array` used less (`array`+1);
2. There is no need of `rcl` displacements for `aligned` while `array` needs them (`aligned`+1), but with them I can control the displacement (`array`+1);
3. `array` is the basic matrix environment, should it be used outside matrices?;
4. The space between lines in `array` is smaller than it is in `aligned`. `aligned` seems much better (`aligned`+1).

From my perspective, `aligned` is much more suitable for this kind of organization, but I don't see anything deeply wrong about `array`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    y(x)  & = y_h(x) + y_p(x)   &   &  &       &  &   &  &       &  &   &  &    &  &     \\
    y(0)  & = y_h(0) + y_p(0)   & = &  & c_1   &  & + &  & c_2   &  & + &  & A  &  & = 2 \\
    y'(0) & = y'_h(0) + y'_p(0) & = &  & - c_1 &  & + &  & 2 c_2 &  & + &  & 3A &  & = 1
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{rlcrrrcrl}
    y(x)  & = y_h(x) + y_p(x)   &   &       &   &       &   &    &     \\
    y(0)  & = y_h(0) + y_p(0)   & = & c_1   & + & c_2   & + & A  & = 2 \\
    y'(0) & = y'_h(0) + y'_p(0) & = & - c_1 & + & 2 c_2 & + & 3A & = 1
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as you've coded these, both are woefully misshapen.  Probably `array` is a better choice since some entries contain a negated element or one with a prime that should be right-aligned.  But the intercolumn space needs to be reduced to zero, and `=` and `+` signs need to be placed in their own columns wrapped in empty groups, e.g., `{}={}`.  You will also need to set `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{nn}`, where "nn" is (at least) the number of `&` you will need plus 1, since the default limit is 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many different alignments in the columns, so `alignedat` becomes quite complicated to manage.

I'd go with a suitable `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  % convenient local assignments
  \newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}
  \newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
  % let TeX compute the spacing
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  % some more space between rows
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{array}{ R C L C L C R C R C R C L }
    y(x)  &=& y_h(x)  &+& y_p(x)  \\
    y(0)  &=& y_h(0)  &+& y_p(0)  &=&  c_1 &+&  c_2 &+&  A &=& 2 \\
    y'(0) &=& y'_h(0) &+& y'_p(0) &=& -c_1 &+& 2c_2 &+& 3A &=& 1
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the usage of `newcolumntype` advisable/preferable? Should I consider it to become a new standard? I really liked the less usage of `&`.

Comment: @FHZ Would you prefer `@{} >{\displaystyle}r >{{}}c<{{}} ...` in the argument to `array`? The `\newcolumntype` declarations will not survive the `equation` environment, so you're free to redefine the column types in convenient ways in other situations.

Comment: That's an interesting option. I knew and I've tested that I can set `\newcolumntype ` globally by placing it in the preamble, as much as for `arraycolsep` and `arraystretch`. So I have flexibility between local and global usage. I also tested a `\newenvironment` which sets all the special configurations on it

Answer (score 1):

There is a third possibility if you want to align equations on multiple columns: the `alignedat` environment. It doesn't add space between columns. And sometimes it can't put correct spaces around `=` or `+`, so the trick with an empty term `={}` or `+{}` is required for that. A code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{8}
    y(x)  &= y_h(x)  &&+ y_p(x)\\
    y(0)  &= y_h(0)  &&+ y_p(0)  &&={}&&c_1 &&+{}&&c_2 &&+{}&&A=2 \\
    y'(0) &= y'_h(0) &&+ y'_p(0) &&= -&&c_1 &&+ 2&&c_2 &&+ 3&&A=1
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Indeed, I tried `alignedat`, but I didn't know the empty trick, as also stated by barbara in a comment  at the question, so it seemed the same as others. Thanks.